# grant usage on schema in PostgreSQL 9.6.3

Tags: postgresql, schema, sql-grant

Following the
[method for PostgresQL 9.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986368/installing-postgresql-extension-to-all-schemas) I try to install an extension available to all users:

```
create schema extensions;
create extension pgcrypto WITH schema extensions;
grant usage on schema extensions to public;
grant execute on all functions in schema extensions to public;
```

Then I request

```
select extensions.gen_salt('bf');
```

under a non-priviledged user, and receive an error message:

```
ERROR:  schema "extensions" does not exist
LINE 1: select extensions.gen_salt('bf');
```

Even

```
create extension pgcrypto schema pg_catalog;
```

does not help. Is this a bug in PostgreSQL 9.6?

Comment: works for me on 9.6.2 (mac)

Comment: maybe you work on different databases?..

Comment: Yes, the databases are different.