# Restoring Postgres database using earthdistance, type "earth" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, search-path, earthdistance

I have a table with a cube column, but restoring the database from pg_dump stopped working from postgres 15.6 (also a problem on postgres 16.3). The error I get is on the function  `ll_to_earth` in the`earthdistance` extension.

`pg_dump` always set the searchpath to empty:
`SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);`

Setting `search_path` doesn't solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591713
. There is no way to set `search_path` on a table, but even setting on a function is not preserved by pg_dump:
`ALTER FUNCTION public.ll_to_earth SET search_path = public;`

Script to reproduce the issue:

```
set -x

psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432 -c "CREATE DATABASE earth_test"

psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test <<EOF
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS cube WITH SCHEMA public;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS earthdistance WITH SCHEMA public;

CREATE TABLE town (
    name varchar,
    lon float,
    lat float,
    location public.cube GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.earth_box(public.ll_to_earth(lat, lon), 0)) STORED
);
EOF

pg_dump postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test > earth_test.sql


psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432 -c "CREATE DATABASE earth_test2";
psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test2 -f earth_test.sql
```

Output:

```
+ psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432 -c 'CREATE DATABASE earth_test'
CREATE DATABASE
+ psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE EXTENSION
CREATE TABLE
+ pg_dump postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test
+ psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432 -c 'CREATE DATABASE earth_test2'
CREATE DATABASE
+ psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test2 -f earth_test.sql
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
 set_config 
------------
 
(1 row)

SET
SET
SET
SET
ALTER SCHEMA
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
SET
psql:earth_test.sql:69: ERROR:  type "earth" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ians($1))*sin(radians($2))),earth()*sin(radians($1)))::earth
                                                                  ^
QUERY:  SELECT cube(cube(cube(earth()*cos(radians($1))*cos(radians($2))),earth()*cos(radians($1))*sin(radians($2))),earth()*sin(radians($1)))::earth
CONTEXT:  SQL function "ll_to_earth" during inlining
```

Comment: Work with us a little. Is this type "earth" defined in the earthdistance extension in the version you are using? If so, what schema is is in (`\dT *.earth`)

Comment: I the the script above, creating the db from scratch. earth is defined in the earthdistance extension distibuted with postgresql 16.2.
`$ psql postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/earth_test
psql (16.2)
Type "help" for help.

earth_test=# \dT *.earth
      List of data types
 Schema | Name  | Description 
--------+-------+-------------
 public | earth | 
(1 row)`

Comment: In that case either the query that is failing has `search_path` set to something that doesn't list the public schema or you aren't running the query on the same database that you created the extension in.

Comment: Yes, it's failing because `pg_dump` always generates a SQL file that sets the `search_path` empty. This breaks the earthdistance extension, making it not possible to restore the database from the dump. I'm wondering what is the proper solution to this problem. All I do is written in the script above.