# Using postgresql extensions with Spring Boot multi tenant application

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on a multi tenant Spring Boot application using Postgresql and different schemas for tenants. Everything works fine until we need to use Postgresql's extensions, then we got errors about missing types.

```
ERROR: function text2ltree(character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 266
```

The extension is installed using Liquibase and I have updated the changesets to perform the following:

```
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ltree WITH SCHEMA myschema;
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path TO "$user", myschema
```

Then I can control where the extension is installed and updating the search path should avoid to specify the schema all the time. I have run the Liquibase migration and check Postgresql configuration for *search_path* and it works. I can run queries (using Squirrel) without the need to include the schema prefix for the *ltree* extension types and functions.

It does not work as expected as I still got the same error message. If I explicitly prefix the *ltree* types and functions with *myschema*, I got an error indicating that the operator is not found.

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: myschema.ltree <@ myschema.ltree
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 263
```

For multi tenancy, we implement a custom `org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider` that sets the schema in the [MultitenantConnectionProvider.getAnyConnection()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/MultiTenantConnectionProvider.html#getAnyConnection()) method.

I want to simplify the setup so I want to avoid to include always the extension's schema, besides the *search_path* configuration, I can not found anything related. Is there a way to implement the described setup to prevent prefixing with the extension schema in all the code?

Comment: 'ALTER DATABASE mydb SET search_path TO "$user", mydb'   Why would add 'mydb' to search_path when that is not how you spelled the schema name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I install the extensions in the *pg_catalog* schema, then everything works as expected. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43937189/6852181).

I want to prevent to install the extensions in the *pg_catalog* schema so, a closer look to the *PGConnection* class reveals that the method to set the default schemas updates the *search_path* value to the schema given.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("SET SESSION search_path TO '");
Utils.escapeLiteral(sb, schema, getStandardConformingStrings());
sb.append("'");
stmt.executeUpdate(sb.toString());
```

It is escaping the *schema* argument, therefore if I try to use multiple schemas separated by commas, the whole expression is escaped.

The solution has been to create my own *setSchema* method in the *MultiTenantConnectionProvider* class. It does the same as the code above but adding my extensions' schema to the *search_path* value.